# Cannot call method 'setData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, d3.js

EDIT 1

Using the method dataTransfer.setData make it works !

http://jsfiddle.net/UH7Sf/1/

```
d3.event.dataTransfer.setData('type',type);
```

---

I'm facing a issue using methods setData and getData within d3.event

I have to div with a draggable img element in the top one, and some drop capabilities on the second one.

```
d3.select('img').on('dragstart', function() { 
    var type = d3.select(this).attr('type');
    console.log("Drag starts with "+ type);
d3.event.transfer.setData('type',type);    
});

d3.select('.drop').on('drop', function() {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
    var type = d3.event.transfer.getData('type');
    console.log("Drag ends with "+ type);      
});

d3.select('.drop').on('dragover', function() {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/UH7Sf/

There is another solution to do this (transfering data within the drag&drop) using d3 ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. `d3.event` doesn't have a `transfer` member.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I need to use dataTransfer not transfer !

Comment: There's no `dataTransfer` either. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying transfer some data from my dragged element to my recipient div.It works with dataTransfer.setData http://jsfiddle.net/UH7Sf/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is no object inside `event` called `transfer`. One thing you can do is try `event.setData()`, but I don't think that's what you want either, because the dragstart and drop events are two different event objects.

You can instead have a separate local variable to use. E.g.

```
var draggedType = null; 

d3.select('img').on('dragstart', function() { 
    var draggedType = d3.select(this).attr('type');
    console.log("Drag starts with "+ draggedType);
});

d3.select('.drop').on('drop', function() {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Drag ends with "+ draggedType);
    // do something with draggedType here

    draggedType = null; // reset draggedType to null when done, just in case
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. My probleme is that the two d3.select().on() need to be executed in two different scope (using some angular directive).